Laravel Echo Presence Channel Custom Authorization Route with Session Data?
I'm using the Presence channel to get the number of LIVE participants of a livestream event and display this #, and the users' first and last names on a page. The issue is that the participants of an event aren't authenticated in any way. I found an answer here on StackOverflow with this code as a bit of a hack to bypass the traditional authentication.
Route::post('/my/custom/broadcast/auth/route', function () {
    $user = new GenericUser(['id' => microtime()]);

    request()->setUserResolver(function () use ($user) {
        return $user;
    });

    return Broadcast::auth(request());
});

Broadcast::channel('my-room-name', function ($user) {
    return [
        'id' => $user->id,
    ];
});

It works, I faked user authentication, I can join the channel and everything. The problem now is that I want the real data of the LIVE participants. I have the participant ID saved in a Laravel session variable, and I have the data of each participant in a table, let's call it participants table. How can I use this session participant ID (or another way!) and pass it in a custom authorization route? I tried a guard and a middleware and couldn't get it to work without the Hacky code mentioned above. Would it be possible to pass data from the frontend in Echo? (See this link):
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#customizing-the-authorization-request
Ideally what I want to have in channels.php is this:
Broadcast::channel('my-room-name', function ($user) {
    return [
        'id' => $user->registrant_id,
        'first_name' => $user->first_name,
        'last_name' => $user->last_name,
    ];
});

How can I do this??
